# LFS error These critical programs are missing or too old: make while compiling glibc

Tags: centos, centos7, glibc, linux-from-scratch

I am following the LFS guide and I am on this step http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/glibc.html . Every time I am compiling glibc-2.33, during the ./configure process I get this error `These critical programs are missing or too old: make`. Doing with root does the exact same thing. When I do make --version it shows this:

````
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. ```
````

Comment: [2.2 Host System Requirements](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter02/hostreqs.html) specifies **Make-4.0** (LFS stable, at the time of this comment is 10.1). There is a script on that page that will output your host (centos?) system's program versions. If you're still having problems, please post the output from that script.

Comment: This is my output ```  makeinfo (GNU texinfo) 5.1```

Comment: You've already posted that your GNU Make version is 3.82... the current stable version of LFS requires version 4.0. `makeinfo` is not the same as `make`.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/74195386/7268445 where I posted an answer for 'too old' make and 'too old' gcc